# Ax2012 New Parameter Value in Contract Not Passed to Data Provider

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, provider, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I had added a new integer parameter method `parmView` into `PurchReqContract` class.
Then I set the  value for this `parmView` in `PurchReqController` `preRunModifyContract` method.
After that I try to retrieve the contract value in `PurchReqDP` `processReport` method but the value does not successfully passed to `PurchReqDP` `processReport`.
I did a `CIL` full compile but no luck. The problem still exist. Please help.

If anyone have experienced on this problem and can provide some
advices? I was using Ax2012 Kernel Version 6.2.1000.1437.

```
==== PurchReqContract.parmView() ===
[DataMemberAttribute('View')]
public int parmView(View _view = view)
{
    view = _view;
    return view;
}


======== PurchReqDP.processReport() =======
contract                = this.parmDataContract() as PurchReqContract;
versionRecId            = contract.parmRecordId();
versionDateTime         = contract.parmVersioningTimeStamp();
requisitionPurpose      = contract.parmRequisitionPurpose();
view = contract.parmView();
```

Comment: i am having similar issue, how did you resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the method to return an integer but your parameter is of type View.

I assume that "View" in the Parameter is an EDT of type integer?
If not, check this.

Only base types can be serialized in DataContract.

Either you change the return type to be View or the parameter type to be int. They have to be the same base type.